# Samsung C480FN Scanner not detected

Tags: drivers, 19.10, scanner, samsung

I am using the 64-bit Ubuntu 19.1. and am trying to install my Samsung MFP C480FN in my LAN. This is a Multifunction Laser-Printer with a Scanner on top. The printer was no problem, but the Scanner is not recognized, although I have installed the correct drivers: https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/samsung-xpress-sl-c480-color-laser-multifunction-printer-series/16462546/model/16462550/swItemId/fp-191129-2

I have installed the driver via `sudo bash install-scanner.sh` and it confirms the proper installation but **Skanlite** doesn't find it. I've not found the Scanner on the 'supported Devices' Site from Skanlite, but I wasn't sure if this list is up-to-date. Any suggestions what else I can do? Thanks

Comment: Check you are actually using Ubuntu, as there  was no 2019-January (19.1) release, though it's possible it was a typo (you tagged 2019-October release I note)

Comment: Yes, its a typo. Thank you. Its 19.10.